# Which test is most appropriate for a relationship between two continuous variables using different scales?

Tags: correlation, continuous-data, pearson-r, spearman-rho, scales

Please forgive me if this is a common query but I haven't seen anything which quite answers what I'm looking for. I'm using data concerning the weight change and pH values of plastic samples, the plastic had two treatments; heat (n = 30) and nutrients (n = 30). There were five exposure intervals in each treatment but due to the sample size being quite small, I'm not expecting to incorporate this into my statistical analysis.

I suspect a relationship between weight change and pH but I'm not sure which test to use. I don't think my data meet the assumptions of Pearson's correlation coefficient so my next best guess would be Spearman's rho but I'm not clear on whether this is the right way to go? Any suggestions on the best action to take or resources to look at moving forward would be most welcome.

Comment: Hi and welcome to CV. I don't understand the question. Since you'd be plotting one value against the other, it doesn't matter if the scale/unit/anything is different. Just scatter plot and you might be able to see or at least guess a relationship.

Comment: Hi @cherub, you're very right.. I was still in a migraine attack when I wrote this so I wasn't thinking straight. I've amended the post as I've managed to plot the data, but I'm still unsure about whether Pearson's would be the right test (relationship seems monotonic with a couple of outliers).